# Visual C++ how to find name of a column in MySql

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-c++

I am currently using the following code to fill a combo box with the column information inside of MySql database:

```
private: void Fillcombo1(void){
              String^ constring=L"datasource=localhost;port=3307;username=root;password=root";
              MySqlConnection^ conDataBase=gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
              MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase= gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from database.combinations ;", conDataBase);
              MySqlDataReader^ myReader;

              try{
              conDataBase->Open();
              myReader=cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();
              while(myReader->Read()){
                String^ vName;
                vName= myReader->GetString("OD");
                comboBox1->Items->Add(vName);
              }
              }catch(Exception^ex){
              MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
              }
             }
```

Is there any simple method for finding the name of the column and placing it within a combo box?

Also, I am adding small details to my app such as a news feed which would need updating every so often, will I have to dedicate a full new database spreadsheet to this single news feed text so that I can updated it or is there a simpler alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: This is more about SQL language than C++ (managed or unmanaged).

Comment: I didnt realise SQL was a full language, I just used MySql for the excel type database, can SQL be used with visual c++? I mean if I program something in SQL will it have an effect or allow me to use the results in visual c++ as part of my GUI?

Comment: SQL statements can be sent to a database that accepts SQL (most do).  SQL is not a part of C++ and cannot be embedded in C++.  Remember that Visual C++ is an IDE and not a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to use the DESCRIBE statement:

```
mysql> describe rcp_categories;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Category   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Category_Text | varchar(32)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.20 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way without launching any other query but you could also use "SHOW COLUMNS" MySQL Query.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM combinations FROM database
```

or

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM database.combinatons
```

Both will work.